# How to find the inverse tangent of a complex number's rectangular form as it relates to pi?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

One of the hints on KhanAcademy appears to skip how they found the inverse tangent as a fraction of pi over a number.

Every time I type this into a calculator it comes up only as a decimal, and I'm not sure how you could find it with pi inside the fraction unless you already memorized the number to 9 digits or something.

---

The main problem:

Express $z_1 = 3\sqrt{3} - 9i$ in polar form.

Express your answer in exact terms, using radians, where you rangle is between 0 and $2\pi$ radians, inclusive.

---

The part that appears to skip how to find the answer as a fraction with pi involved:

Finding $\theta$

Using the formula, we have:

$\theta = \tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})$

$\theta = \tan^{-1}(\frac{-9}{3\sqrt{3}})$

$\theta = -\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please take a moment to type out the equations (they're just a few lines long) rather than providing links to images. Here's a [quick guide](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to formatting.

Comment: As for your question, you're wondering why $\arctan(-\sqrt 3) = -\frac\pi3$? Are you familiar with radians?

Comment: @Théophile I am familiar with radians as well as some values around the 30-60-90 and 45-45-90 triangles. But I still fail to see how to use this knowledge to know the arctangent with pi as part of the fraction rather than just a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have the requisite knowledge of radians and the unit circle in this answer.

Your question just seems to be a question on why $\arctan({-\sqrt{3}}) = -\frac{\pi}{3}$. The definition of $\arctan$ is just the inverse of the tangent function. If you know how to take the tangent of an angle, then you know the arctangent. If I want the value of $\arctan(x)$, then the arctangent function just asks "What ANGLE do I need to make such that the tangent of that angle is $x$?"

In your case, you want $\arctan({-\sqrt{3}}).$ On the unit circle, what ANGLE do I need to make from the axis such that the tangent of that angle is $-\sqrt{3}$? The answer? $-\frac{\pi}{3}$. And you can verify that $\tan(\frac{-\pi}{3}) = -\sqrt{3}$.

This is assuming you have the requisite knowledge of the unit circle to deduce that $\tan({\frac{-\pi}{3}}) = -\sqrt{3},$ though. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I understand the relationship between tan and arctan, I just don't know how to find the answer to arctan as a fraction with pi involved rather than just a long decimal that shows in the calculator.

Comment: @Typhic Would you be able to give $\arctan(-\sqrt3)$ in degrees?

Comment: @Typhic, as the previous comment mentions, your problem is likely with radians, then. We discuss angles in terms of radians. So when you take the tangent of an angle, we don't use degrees. We use radians, which involve $\pi$. $-\frac{\pi}{3}$ represents 60 degrees, but the negative sign means it's below the $x-$-axis.

Comment: @Théophile Converting to degrees by multiplying 180 degrees / pi radians = -60 degrees, which does match a special angle. If it wasn't a special angle, would it be much harder to find it as a fraction with pi?

Comment: Fractions of $\pi$ only work for very special angles. It doesn't always work. For example, $\tan{\pi}{3}$, $\tan{\pi}{4}$, $\tan{\pi}{6}$ have very nice answers because those are familiar angles that you know. However, $\tan{\pi}{7}$ doesn't have a nice answer like that, and you can only do a decimal with it. Really, only 30,60,90, and a few other select ones you can get a nice answer with $\pi$

Comment: @Typhic Right, $\frac\pi3$ works out nicely in the same way that $60^\circ$ is a convenient angle. Certainly if the angle were $97^\circ$, say, then it wouldn't have a nice representation in radians either.

Comment: @Théophile How would you go about doing it in reverse such that you could get a radical instead of a long decimal--this would be to find the a in a+bi rectangular form. I've tried using the calculator and converting to radians but it doesn't seem to work the same way.

$a = rcos\theta$

$a = 6cos135^\circ$

$a = -3\sqrt{2}$

I can verify but, but I do not know how to convert the decimal I get from the calculator to a nice looking radical.

Comment: I notice you're @'ing the other person, but I can still give you my answer. You can't always do it in reverse, either. Nice angles like $30, 60, 90, 45$ give good answers for trig values in terms of radicals. This won't happen, always. It happens for some other angles, like $22.5$, $15,$ and $36$ degrees, though those you may have not seen before. Other than those (and a few others,) you really don't get nice radical answers.

Comment: @Luna145 I'm still new to the exchange websites so not 100% on the methods. Sorry if I should have been @'ing you. Does everyone in the comments get pinged even without me @'ing a specific person, and if so, should I not @'?

Comment: Everyone gets pinged. I thought you were just looking for a response from him/ her, haha.

Comment: So do you happen to know how they were able to get such a clean radical from the equation for $a = 6cos135^\circ$? Because, when I do it it just comes out as a decimal on the calculator even with converting to radians.

Comment: I figured it out. If I can separate the 135 into two special angles I can use a trig identity equation to evaluate.

Comment: That's the way to do it. You should think about $\sin$, $\cos$, and $\tan$ in terms of points on the unit circle. If you can do that, you can make a triangle and figure them out exactly. In fact, trig identities are how those angles that I mentioned before like $22.5$ and $15$ are found. You can use a "half-angle" formula to do those. And then you can use similar addition formulas to get angles like $37.5$, $52.5$, and many others.

Comment: And more on that "making triangles on the unit circle thing." You don't need an addition formula to find $\tan(135)$. Measure $135$ degrees going counterclockwise from the $x$-axis, and you land yourself on the unit circle in the second quadrant. Draw the point on the unit circle with radius $1$, and you can use some triangle stuff to figure that the coordinate of the point on the unit circle with an angle of $135$ is $( \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}).$ The $x$-coordinate gives you cosine, and the $y$ coordinate gives you sine. Tangent is the quotient, which gives you $-1$.